# Using jQuery to autosize columns to have same height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar and content area, each with an unique background colour. They both float so I am unable to get the 2 to be the same size so that they can spread all the way to the bottom. I figured with jQuery I could determine each columns height, then autosize the other column so that they are the same height, but my script returns the value in px's so I cannot do a direct comparison.

Is there another, maybe better way, you can advise me?

```
// Sample code:
var left_bar = $("#left_bar").css("height");
var content_area = $("#content_area").css("height");
if(left_bar > content_area) {
    $("#content_area").attr("height",left_bar);
} else {
    $("#sidebar").attr("height",content_area);
}
```

Comment: remove de px part of the string first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.height()` instead of `attr('height', left_bar)` - this will give you a number value.

```
var a = $('#left_bar'), b = $('#content_area');

if (a.height() > b.height()) {
 b.height(a.height()); 
} else {
 a.height(b.height()); 
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/olopuy/1/edit

You may also be able to get what you want without any JS; see http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 0):

```
var left_bar = $("#left_bar").height();
var content_area = $("#content_area").height();
if(left_bar > content_area) {
    $("#content_area").attr("height",left_bar);
} else {
    $("#sidebar").attr("height",content_area);
}
```

will give you a number instead of a number with px behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that combines a couple of tricks to do it all in just a few lines of code:

```
$c = $('#left_bar,#content_area');
$c.height( Math.max.apply( // find the max of all elements in an array
    Math, $.map($c,function(v){   // build an array of heights
        return $(v).height(); 
    })
));
```

Which can even be compressed into one line:

```
$c = $('#left_bar,#content_area');
$c.height(Math.max.apply(Math,$.map($c,function(v){return $(v).height();})));
```